# php to JS long text -- ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor

I got a long text that I manage to store in my database(mysql). I can get the data from database to php, there is also no problem with that. In order to put the long text to ckeditor,

```
function getDetails(text,did,title){


    // tersine replace işlemleri
    // syntax hatamızı çözdük, şimdi textlerimizde bulunan quot; ları eskisi gibi " lara çevirelim


    console.log(text);

      $("#editor").css("visibility","visible");
      $("#info").css("visibility","visible");

     ineditor = "<textarea class='ckeditor' name='editor1' cols='30' rows='10'></textarea>";
     CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(text);
     $("#info").html(title);
     $("#btnUpdate").attr("onclick","updateNews("+did+")");

}
```

this is the code Im getting the long text as text parameter. and I send it from php like this :

```
$text=json_encode($text);
   $title= json_encode($title);

echo "\n<td id='text$rec[0]' ondblclick='imageClickNews($rec[0]1)' onclick='getDetails($text, $rec[0], $title)'>$rec[1]</td>
```

By using onClick on `<td>`

I think after some point of my Long Text , it doesn`t read the rest.. What should I do ? 
Thanks

Comment: Try to clean up the code a little. Reduce the example to contain only relevant parts. For example, is the `ineditor` variable ever used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you think more of the HTML and JS being generated and not the PHP when it comes to CKEditor. I suggest that you output the HTML as HTML and not as a JavaScript variable, concider maybe using something like the **rendered** and untested HTML below - a big change, yes, but I think worth it:

```
<script>
function setDataTitleAndClickHandler(dataElementID, dataTitleID, thingID) {
    var htmldata = $('#' + dataElementID).html();
    var titledata = $('#' + dataTitleID).html();

    $("#editor").css("visibility","visible");
    $("#info").css("visibility","visible");

    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(htmldata);
    $("#info").html(titledata);
    $("#btnUpdate").attr("onclick", "updateNews(" + thingID + ")");
}
</script>
<tr>
    <td onclick="getDetails('foo-data', 'foo-title', 12345)">
        <div id="foo-title">"It's a mad world" - Anon</div>
        <div style="display:none;" id="foo-data">
            <p>Content from DB to CKE via PHP.</p>
            <p>"It's a mad world" - Anonymous.</p>
        </div>
        <p>Visible stuff here</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="btnUpdate">Update :D</button>
```

The benefit here is that you don't need to think about formatting very much and the HTML is self-contained, easy to debug. Also this pattern is easily repeatable and should be very easy to both namespace and render in PHP. Does this method satisfy your situation?

Comment: I appriciate your effort however, the 'htmldata' is stored in my database, it is not in the html.. So, I cannot reach it via $('#' + dataElemetID).html() ----
I need to use php to get it, the source of problem is the method getDetails`s parameter(text) cannot handle long string.. I`m trying to find a better way too like using ajax to get the data directly from php and put it in ckeditor.. this wouldn`t help me but thanks :)

Comment: @ozn Yes... here the data is still stored and fetched from the database :) My whole point was that my example was the *rendered* HTML, not the backend PHP. So you would render this from PHP and PHP would fetch the data from the DB normally. Do you get what I mean by rendered HTML?

Comment: So your PHP might look something like this: `<div style="display:none;" id="foo-data"><?php echo $myDataFetchedFromDatabase; ?></div>` for the HTML data part. See what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
onclick='getDetails($text, $rec[0], $title)'
```

Is embedding php into javascript.
In JavaScript you have to embrace the string values in double quotes.
So lets say your `$text == 'rabbit'` and `$title == 'fairy'`.
Here is what you get in HTML:

```
<td onclick='getDetails( rabbit , 0, fairy )'...
```

Here is what you **should** have in HTML to make it correct:

```
<td onclick='getDetails( "rabbit" , 0, "fairy" )'
```

So the final PHP code would be:

```
echo "\n<td id='text$rec[0]' ondblclick='imageClickNews($rec[0]1)' onclick='getDetails(\"$text\", $rec[0], \"$title\")'>$rec[1]</td>
```

And I don't know about `did`, do the same there if it's textual too.

Comment: $text=json_encode($text);
       $title= json_encode($title); I Use these instead.. That didnt solve the problem

Comment: you are not wrong, I just forgot to tell you that I used json_encode

Comment: This is still quite a bad idea. Imagine what is stored in the database; what if there is content like `<p>"I'm a magical princess & so are you!" - Everyone everywhere</p>\n<p>I &lt;3 Kittens!!</p>`. What happens to the quotes then? JSONifying it is a better solution, but I think using the raw HTML by injecting it into the DOM when the HTML is being generated by PHP is the simplest solution.